# Please help me out, i want to display the linked list, reverse it & display then again display it

Tags: c, list, linked-list

can someone help me out in reversing the linked list? coz after reversing the list is gone when i select display....
there must be some way to print the reverse of the list which will stay in the head....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<alloc.h>
typedef struct nodes
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}
node;
void display(node*);
void display(node *head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d)->",head->data);
        head=head->next;
    }
}
void main()
{
node *head,*p,*q,*r;
int i,n,x,e,temp,a,b,c;
clrscr();
printf("\nENTER NUMBER OF DATA TO BE ENTERED: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
printf("\nENTER DATA NUMBER 1: ");
scanf("%d",&(head->data));
head->next=NULL;
p=head;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    p->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    p=p->next;
    p->next=NULL;
    printf("ENTER DATA NUMBER %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(p->data));
}
while(1)
{
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tMEGA LINKED LIST PROGRAM");
    printf("\n1]Display Linked List.");
    printf("\n2]Delete Linked List.");
    printf("\n3]Re-edit linked List.");
    printf("\n4]Add Node @1st Position.");
    printf("\n5]Add Node @Last Position.");
    printf("\n6]Re-Create Linked List!!");
    printf("\n7]Sort Linked List");
    printf("\n8]Count Total Nodes.");
    printf("\n9]Reverse Linked List.");
    printf("\n10]EXIT!!");
    printf("\n\n: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    switch(x)
    {
    case 1:
        if(head==(0||NULL))
        {
            printf("\nLIST IS EITHER EMPTY OR DELETED!!");
        }
        else
        {       printf("\nYOUR LINKED LIST: ");
            p=head;
            while(p!=NULL)
            {
                printf("%d)->",p->data);
                p=p->next;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if(head!=(NULL||0))
        {
            for(i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    p=head;
                    head=head->next;
                    free(p);
                }
                while(head->next!=NULL);
            }
            printf("\nYOUR LINKED LIST HAS BEEN DELETED");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNO LINKED LIST AVAILABLE TO DELETE!!");
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if(head==(NULL||0))
        {
            printf("\nNOT APPLICABLE!!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nRE-ENTER DATA NUMBER 1: ");
            scanf("%d",&head->data);
            head->next=NULL;
            p=head;
            for(i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                p->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                p=p->next;
                p->next=NULL;
                printf("RE-ENTER DATA NUMBER %d: ",i+1);
                scanf("%d",&(p->data));
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if(head!=(0||NULL))
        {
            p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            printf("\nENTER DATA FOR POSITION 1: ");
            scanf("%d",&(p->data));
            p->next=head;
            head=p;
            display(head);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNOT APPLICABLE!!");
        }
        break;

    case 5:
        if(head!=(0||NULL))
        {
            p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            printf("\nENTER DATA FOR LAST POSITION: ");
            scanf("%d",&(p->data));
            p->next=NULL;
            if(head==NULL)
            display(head);
            q=head;
            while(q->next!=NULL)
            q=q->next;
            q->next=p;
            display(head);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNOT APPLICABLE!!");
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        if(head!=(NULL|0))
        {
            printf("\nDELETE THE CURRENT LINKED LIST BEFORE CREATING A NEW ONE!!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nENTER NUMBER OF DATA TO BE ENTERED: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            printf("\nENTER DATA NUMBER 1: ");
            scanf("%d",&(head->data));
            head->next=NULL;
            p=head;
            for(i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                p->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                p=p->next;
                p->next=NULL;
                printf("ENTER DATA NUMBER %d: ",i+1);
                scanf("%d",&(p->data));
            }
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        if(head!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\nBEFORE SORTING: ");
            display(head);
            q=head;
            while(q!=NULL)
            {
                p=q->next;
                while(p!=NULL)
                {
                    if((q->data)>(p->data))
                    {
                        temp=q->data;
                        q->data=p->data;
                        p->data=temp;
                    }
                    p=p->next;
                }
                q=q->next;
            }
            p=head;
            printf("\n\nAFTER SORTING: ");
            display(head);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNOT APPLICABLE!!");
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        if(head!=NULL)
        {
            p=head;
            for(temp=0;p!=NULL;temp++)
            {
                p=p->next;
            }
            printf("\nTOTAL NODES: %d",temp);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNOT APPLICABLE!!");
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("\nSTILL WORKING ON THIS CODE!!");
        break;
    case 10:
        printf("\nARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO EXIT?");
        printf("\n\n1>Yes!\t\t2>NO!");
        printf("\n\n: ");
        scanf("%d",&e);
        if(e==1)
        {
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            if(e==2)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\t\tINVALID SELECTION!!");
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n\t\tINVALID SELECTION!!");
        break;
    }

   }
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Nobody's going to read all this. Some tips: 1. Why are you writing `void main()`? That's not C. 2. Don't cast the return from `malloc()`. 3. Format your code properly. 4. Learn what a function is, that huge `main()` function is awful, no wonder you can't figure out what's going wrong, you're duplicating code multiple times that belongs in functions, every time you duplicate code it gives you as many more opportunities to make mistakes as you have statements in it.

Comment: Please consider providing the community with a short and reproducible version of your code so we can better help you. Also, please add more information about the results you're expecting as well as what you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program fails to reverse a list is because when the user chooses menu option 9, all they get is a print statement declaring the code isn't working yet.

At a high level, reversing a linked list can be accomplished like this:

```
for each element in the input list, from beginning to end:
    remove element from input list
    place element in the beginning of the output list
return output list
```